# How to use the Count in Where Query to filter only the Group by is > 1?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to use the Count in Where Query to filter only the Group by is > 1?

Im my query I am trying: `=query($A$1:$J$16; "select A, count(D), sum(E)  **where C='USER2' count(D)>1** group by A")`

But it's not working.

With: `=query($A$1:$J$16; "select A, count(D), sum(E)  where C='USER2' group by A")`

it's ok, but I need to count the `Sum(E)` only when `count(D) > 1`!

This is my table: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PMg9_qudC841TqCoeVQH2mwEG4FLuxqBla9l7aaXIQw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: After the player0 amazing answer I found some info about Pivot Table in use to help to summarize data.

Info from google: https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308944?hl=en

Thanks player0 for support.

PS: His query is perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(QUERY({A1:E16}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col5) 
  where Col3 = 'USER2' 
  group by Col1 
  pivot Col4"); 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col2-Col3 
  where Col2>Col3 
  label Col1'date',Col2'sum of check',Col3'sum of valid',Col2-Col3'difference'")
```

[image]